# Конвертация .py в .exe в Python 3.7.3

Tags: python

Имею самый обыкновенный код на `python`. 
Хотел поделиться этим кодом для другого компьютера. (**на другом ПК нет python**)

Искал много информации по данной теме. Пользуюсь `pip pyinstaller`. Однако, когда я запускаю в cmd:  **pyinstaller test.py** - то получаю ошибку синтаксиса 
<<Вывод консоли>>

```
C:\Users\Pavel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>pyinstaller tes
t.py
1017 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
1017 INFO: Python: 3.7.3
1018 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
1021 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Pavel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Script
s\test.spec
1023 INFO: UPX is not available.
1032 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Pavel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Users\\Pavel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Scripts']
1032 INFO: checking Analysis
1033 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
1034 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1040 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
1117 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
25954 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
27584 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
27742 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of
final executable
  required by c:\users\pavel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.ex
e
35733 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Pavel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\S
cripts\test.py

Syntax error in C:\Users\Pavel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts
\test.py


                                  ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Искал ответы на этот вопрос и в итоге просят переместить Python в дерево, где не будет русских символов, однако на этом пути нет ни 1 символа. Смотрел так же видео ролики и у них работало со стандартным путём. Прошу помочь, мучаюсь уже вторую ночь. Даже успел переустановить систему

Windows 7 (не сборка = чистая Windows)
x86

```
    import random, time
n=int(input('\n\n\nсколько раз повторять?      \n'))
i = int(0)
while i < n:
    time.sleep(3)
    f = random.random()
    if f > 0.8:
        print('''


            Text


        ''')    if f < 0.8:
        print('''


            Text


        ''')
    elif f < 0.6:
        print('''   


            Text


            ''')
    elif f < 0.4:
        print('''   


            Text


            ''')
    elif f < 0.2:
        print('''


            Text


            ''')
    i =i+1 
time.sleep(5)
print('The hacking process has begun')
time.sleep(3)
print('Closing a program will not end this process')
time.sleep(3)
print('Connecting libraries')
#print('5%\n10%\n20%\n30%\n40%\n50%\n60%\n70%\n80%\n90%\n95%\n96%\n97%\n98%\n99%')
#print('5%','10%','20%','30%','40%','50%','60%','70%','80%','90%','95%','96%','97%','98%','99%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 5%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 10%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 15%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 20%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 25%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 30%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 40%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 50%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 60%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 70%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 75%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 85%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 90%')
time.sleep(3)
print('Loading... 95%')
time.sleep(3)
print('Loading... 96%')
time.sleep(3)
print('Loading... 97%')
time.sleep(3)
print('Loading... 98%')
time.sleep(3)
print('Loading... 99%')
time.sleep(3)
print('Данная программа не причинит вреда вашему компьютеру.')
time.sleep(3)
print('''

    Хорошего дня :D

    ''')
input()
```

Comment: написано `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, что значит инвалидный синтаксис) а вообще прикрепите лучше код, но скорее всего ошибка может быть действительно в кодировке..

Comment: Как понять это? Ошибка в кодировке? Кодировка чего?

Comment: имеется в виду, что есть не читаемые символы, но вообще написано про синтаксическую ошибку в файле `test.py`, так что ждем код

Comment: Я же правильно понял, что проблема может быть в записи кода?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/Pavel/Desktop/Test.txt Я не уверен, что ссылка рабочая, редактор не очень понятный для меня, прошу извинить, если что то не так

Comment: просто копируйте код из `test.py` и вставьте в вопрос..

Comment: Да, я так и сделал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в коде были явные **синтаксические ошибки**, если, конечно, вы приложили исходный\точный вариант. я поправил:

```py
import random, time
n = int(input('\n\n\nсколько раз повторять?      \n'))
i = int(0)
while i < n:
    time.sleep(3)
    f = random.random()
    if f > 0.8:
        print('''


            Text


        ''')    
    if f < 0.8:
        print('''


            Text


        ''')
    elif f < 0.6:
        print('''   


            Text


            ''')
    elif f < 0.4:
        print('''   


            Text


            ''')
    elif f < 0.2:
        print('''


            Text


            ''')
    i += 1 
time.sleep(5)
print('The hacking process has begun')
time.sleep(3)
print('Closing a program will not end this process')
time.sleep(3)
print('Connecting libraries')
#print('5%\n10%\n20%\n30%\n40%\n50%\n60%\n70%\n80%\n90%\n95%\n96%\n97%\n98%\n99%')
#print('5%','10%','20%','30%','40%','50%','60%','70%','80%','90%','95%','96%','97%','98%','99%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 5%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 10%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 15%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 20%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 25%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 30%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 40%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 50%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 60%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 70%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 75%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 85%')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading... 90%')
time.sleep(3)
print('Loading... 95%')
time.sleep(3)
print('Loading... 96%')
time.sleep(3)
print('Loading... 97%')
time.sleep(3)
print('Loading... 98%')
time.sleep(3)
print('Loading... 99%')
time.sleep(3)
print('Данная программа не причинит вреда вашему компьютеру.')
time.sleep(3)
print('''

    Хорошего дня :D

    ''')
input()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Очень давно мучаюсь и даже не мог подумать, что проблема окажется в коде... СПАСИБО!

Comment: @Pavel не за что) это какая то шутка, как я понял?

Comment: Да, именно так :D

Comment: @Pavel в таком случае лучше использовать батники, они проще и надежнее..

Comment: А у вас есть какая-нибудь статья на эту тему? Просто мне интересна данная тема и я бы хотел разобраться в ней по лучше.

Comment: @Pavel какая тема? шуткавирусы?) это просто гуглится по запросу "вирус .bat", то есть команды самой системе, самое банальное запуск множества окон браузера, что сильно подгрузит оперативу и вряд ли понравится кому либо..